# Dell inspiron 1525

Tags: system-installation

Looking to possibly install Ubuntu on this but have heard of problems with only 2 gigs of ram. Would this laptop with a 2 GHz dual core processor, 2 gigs of ram, run smoothly, or at least better than Vista. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made the switch about a year ago. Recently my laptop crashed (bad mobo) and I had the Dell Inspiron 1525 laying around so I decided to give it a shot, mine has (4 gigs of ram and the T8300 Processor). It runs everything fine. Why not just upgrade the ram, it's a cheap upgrade to make. Whether it will run better than Vista is a tough question to answer, but my guess would be yes. Ubuntu seems to run better than any windows platform I have used. I have had a couple of graphics issues, with artifacts on the display, but I am working them out. Good Luck.